# Android ProcessBuilder

Tags: android, shell, processbuilder

I'm trying to mount an nfs share in an Android application. I'm using ProcessBuilder to call the command:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/system/xbin/busybox", "/system/bin/mount", "-v", "-t", "nfs", "-o", "nolock,rw,vers=3", "192.168.1.11:/media/user", "/mnt/media_rw/remote");
```

Everything is well and I can `ls` the `/mnt/media_rw/remote` with another ProcessBuilder.

But when trying to access it via console, it doesn't show anything! Even under `mount` I can't see it.